# MATLAB input struct with unsigned char into MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex

I tried to input this struct from MATLAB into my MEX file: `struct('speed',{100.3},'nr',{55.4},'on',{54})`, but the last value which is defined in my MEX file as `unsigned char` reads out as zero before calling my C function? The two double values works like intended.

```
struct post_TAG
{
    double speed;
    double nr;
    unsigned char on;  
};
const char *keys[] = { "speed", "nr", "on" };

void testmex(post_TAG *post)
{     
...
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    post_TAG post;
    int numFields, i;
    const char *fnames[3];
    mxArray *tmp;
    double *a,*b;
    unsigned char *c;    

    numFields=mxGetNumberOfFields(prhs[0]);

    for(i=0;i<numFields;i++)
       fnames[i] = mxGetFieldNameByNumber(prhs[0],i);  

    tmp = mxGetField(prhs[0],0,fnames[0]);
    a=(double*)mxGetData(tmp);
    tmp = mxGetField(prhs[0],0,fnames[1]);  
    b=(double*)mxGetData(tmp); 
    tmp = mxGetField(prhs[0],0,fnames[2]);
    c=(unsigned char*)mxGetData(tmp);

    mexPrintf("POST0, speed=%f, nr=%f, on=%u\n",*a,*b,*c); 
    post.speed = *a;
    post.nr = *b;
    post.on = *c; 
    testmex(&post);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `struct` defined as `struct('speed',{100.3},'nr',{55.4},'on',{54})`, the field `on` is a `double`.  Pass as a `uint8` from MATLAB:

```
struct('speed',{100.3},'nr',{55.4},...
    'on',{uint8(54)}),
```

Any numeric value without a specified type in MATLAB is a `double`.

Also note that for reading a scalar value, the problem is simplified somewhat by `mxGetScalar`.  It will return one `double` value for any underlying data type.

```
unsigned char s = (unsigned char) mxGetScalar(...); // cast a double to unsigned char
```

Comment: Also note that instead of `(double*)mxGetData` you should do `mxGetPr`. One less cast is a good thing IMO.

Comment: @Henrik No problem.  Did it help?  If so please accept (green check), and up vote it you want.